# How to add imageView automatic from input in the Editext

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, imageview

I have a Editext and one Button (in Activity1),when user write number(n) in Edittext and click Button=>show (n) ImageView(empty but can take image from SD Card) in Activity2.
What should I do.anyone help me??

Here ,my code.But it not work??i don't know.:(

Activity A

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button button;
EditText editext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    editext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textview);


    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowImages.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", Integer.parseInt(editext.getText().toString()));
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

}

Activity B

```
 public class ShowImages extends Activity {

    ImageView[] imageView;
    private LinearLayout myLInearLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_images);

        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        int text1 = intent1.getIntExtra("intVariableName",0);
        showimage(text1);
    }
public void showimage(int b){

    myLInearLayout =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln1);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    myLInearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i=0;i<b;i++){

    imageView[i]=new ImageView(this)
    ;
    imageView[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_2)
    ;
    myLInearLayout.addView(imageView[i]);
    }
    }}
```

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: You need to create Image View programmatically(without layout) based on inputs.

Comment: @Darshil ,thanks.i trying now.:)

Answer (score 0):

Pass your number to Activity2 using [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Read [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) also

After you passed data, read image from memory. You may use [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)

For adding `ImageView` programmatically you have to inflate it from layout:

```
imageView[i] = (ImageView)LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image, myLInearLayout, false);
imageView[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_2);
myLInearLayout.addView(imageView[i]);
```

R.layout.image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Thanks,but how to show imageView in Activity2.it important.:(